# Stringifying an object with nested arrays of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, stringify

```
JSON=new Object();JSON.stringify=function(e){var e=e;var c={}.hasOwnProperty?true:false;var d=function(i){return i<10?"0"+i:i};var a={"\b":"\\b","\t":"\\t","\n":"\\n","\f":"\\f","\r":"\\r",'"':'\\"',"\\":"\\\\"};function b(i){if(/["\\\x00-\x1f]/.test(i)){return'"'+i.replace(/([\x00-\x1f\\"])/g,function(k,j){var l=a[j];if(l){return l}return j})+'"'}return'"'+i+'"'}function f(q){var m=["["],j,p,k=q.length,n;for(p=0;p<k;p+=1){n=q[p];switch(typeof n){case"undefined":case"function":case"unknown":break;default:if(j){m.push(",")}m.push(n==null?"null":JSON.parse(n));j=true}}m.push("]");return m.join("")}function h(i){return'"'+i.getFullYear()+"-"+d(i.getMonth()+1)+"-"+d(i.getDate())+"T"+d(i.getHours())+":"+d(i.getMinutes())+":"+d(i.getSeconds())+'"'}function g(n){if(typeof n=="undefined"||n===null){return"null"}else{if(n instanceof Date){return h(n)}else{if(typeof n=="string"){return b(n)}else{if(typeof n=="number"){return isFinite(n)?String(n):"null"}else{if(typeof n=="boolean"){return String(n)}else{if(n instanceof Array){return f(n)}else{var k=["{"],j,m,l;for(m in n){l=n[m];switch(typeof l){case"undefined":case"function":case"unknown":break;default:if(j){k.push(",")}k.push(g(m),":",l===null?"null":g(l));j=true}}k.push("}");return k.join("")}}}}}}}return g(e)};JSON.parse=function(json){return eval("("+json+")")};

        var myUserObject = {
                    "name": "John Doe",
                    "company": "Oracle",
                    "twitter" : "@johndoe",      
                  };


        myNewObject['users']=[];
        myNewObject['users'].push(myUserObject);

    alert(myNewObject.users[0].name)



var myFile = new File ("~/Desktop/test.json");

    if(myFile.open("w")){
        myFile.encoding = "UTF-8";
        myFile.write(JSON.stringify(myNewObject, undefined, "\r\n"));
        myFile.close();

        }
```

I am trying to add an object into an array of objects and stringify the object. When I push one object into another I can access the data correctly via an alert but when I write the object to a file via stringify the file is empty.

Comment: `JSON=new Object();` is going to overwrite the native `JSON` object and the next command `JSON.stringify()`, will fail because a new Object doesn't have a `stringify()` method. Why are you doing this?

Comment: If I change :
 myFile.write(JSON.stringify(myNewObject, undefined, "\r\n"));
To this:
 myFile.write(JSON.stringify(myUserObject, undefined, "\r\n"));

The object is correctly stringified. Its only when I try and push an object inside an array that I get an error on main

Comment: You should not overwrite the object.. :S Try using the native one ^^

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of **[how to use JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** in particular and how to reference objects (in general) is the issue here.

Your new Object should not be assigned to `JSON` because `JSON` is a native object. You doing this wipes out that object reference.

Even if you didn't wipe out your reference to the native `JSON` object, `JSON.stringify` is a method and should have what you want stringified passed as an argument to it. You don't assign a function to it because that will wipe out the function already stored there.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify);  // The native object is ready to go
JSON = new Object();          // This wipes out your reference to the object
console.log(JSON.stringify);  // Now, the method doesn't exist!
```

Just assign the object you need stringified to a variable and pass that to `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
var myNewObject = {key1:true, key2:17, key3: [
  {k1: 10, k2:true, k3: "test" },
  {k1: 11, k2:true, k3: "testing" },
  {k1: false, k2:42, k3: "foo" },
]}; // Your object that needs stringification

var stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(myNewObject);   // Stringify it!
console.log(stringifiedObject);                        // Done!
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Scott. I have a quick follow up question, if I wanted to have key3: be an array of multiple objects how would I get that to stringify?

Comment: @bhamlefty24 You don't do anything special at all. Just pass the the main object to `.stringify()` and it will be completely stringified. I'll update the answer to show this.